# Tor - refresh your path every x seconds

Tags: exit-relays

Is there a way to refresh your path in Tor every x seconds or minutes without manually doing like pressing new identity? I need it to do it automatically (e.g. putting a line in the torrc file)? I looked online but couldn't find any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for the torrc option [MaxCircuitDirtiness](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#MaxCircuitDirtiness), which defaults to 10 minutes.

This is assuming that you're doing something low-level, i.e. not using a browser, because the option only applies to new TCP connections. Existing connections don't get closed automatically!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this: /etc/init.d/tor restart

Comment: How would that work as a repeated process? If you're suggesting a cronjob then please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Write a script (or maybe you can find a pre-made one) to loop a "NEWNYM"(New Identity) to the controller (port 9060). There's a built-in 10 second limit to how fast you can send a signal. But even that could be harsh on the network. So don't cycle so often/frequently.

I'd recommended using Stem (TOR's Python Library) to write your script.
https://stem.torproject.org/